# How do I turn off (sleep) one monitor?

Tags: macos, display

I have an MBP (lid closed) that drives two monitors. However, I only once in a while need the second monitor. Is there a way to put it to sleep, without sleeping the other monitor? Note that the monitor that I want to sleep is an LG specifically made for Mac, and which doesn't have any buttons (and it also serves as a USB hub for keyboard, ethernet, sound system).

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/412980/151404